# Binary Bomb Lab Phase 9 -stuck

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm really stuck on Bomb Lab Phase 9 and was looking for some tips/suggestions.

Here is my assembly code:

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_9:
   0x08048fc8 <+0>: push   %ebx
   0x08048fc9 <+1>: sub    $0x18,%esp
   0x08048fcc <+4>: movl   $0xa,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048fd4 <+12>: movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048fdc <+20>: mov    0x20(%esp),%eax
   0x08048fe0 <+24>: mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048fe3 <+27>: call   0x80488d0 <strtol@plt>
   0x08048fe8 <+32>: mov    %eax,%ebx
   0x08048fea <+34>: lea    -0x1(%eax),%eax
   0x08048fed <+37>: cmp    $0x3e8,%eax
   0x08048ff2 <+42>: jbe    0x8048ff9 <phase_9+49>
   0x08048ff4 <+44>: call   0x8049353 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ff9 <+49>: mov    %ebx,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048ffd <+53>: movl   $0x804d0a0,(%esp)
   0x08049004 <+60>: call   0x8048f77 <fun9>
=> 0x08049009 <+65>: cmp    $0x7,%eax
   0x0804900c <+68>: je     0x8049013 <phase_9+75>
   0x0804900e <+70>: call   0x8049353 <explode_bomb>
   0x08049013 <+75>: add    $0x18,%esp
   0x08049016 <+78>: pop    %ebx
   0x08049017 <+79>: ret
```

And here is the assembly code for a Function 9 inside:

```
Dump of assembler code for function fun9:
   0x08048f77 <+0>: push   %ebx
   0x08048f78 <+1>: sub    $0x18,%esp
   0x08048f7b <+4>: mov    0x20(%esp),%edx
   0x08048f7f <+8>: mov    0x24(%esp),%ecx
   0x08048f83 <+12>: test   %edx,%edx
   0x08048f85 <+14>: je     0x8048fbe <fun9+71>
   0x08048f87 <+16>: mov    (%edx),%ebx
   0x08048f89 <+18>: cmp    %ecx,%ebx
   0x08048f8b <+20>: jle    0x8048fa0 <fun9+41>
   0x08048f8d <+22>: mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048f91 <+26>: mov    0x4(%edx),%eax
   0x08048f94 <+29>: mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048f97 <+32>: call   0x8048f77 <fun9>
   0x08048f9c <+37>: add    %eax,%eax
   0x08048f9e <+39>: jmp    0x8048fc3 <fun9+76>
   0x08048fa0 <+41>: mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x08048fa5 <+46>: cmp    %ecx,%ebx
   0x08048fa7 <+48>: je     0x8048fc3 <fun9+76>
   0x08048fa9 <+50>: mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048fad <+54>: mov    0x8(%edx),%eax
   0x08048fb0 <+57>: mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048fb3 <+60>: call   0x8048f77 <fun9>
   0x08048fb8 <+65>: lea    0x1(%eax,%eax,1),%eax
   0x08048fbc <+69>: jmp    0x8048fc3 <fun9+76>
   0x08048fbe <+71>: mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
=> 0x08048fc3 <+76>: add    $0x18,%esp
   0x08048fc6 <+79>: pop    %ebx
   0x08048fc7 <+80>: ret
```

**Here's what I know:**

- It's a number greater than 0
- The `$eax` inside of `fun9` must return a 7
- The `$edx` inside `fun9` has a 75 inside, and the `$ebx` increments/decrements
  depending on whether the input number is less than/greater than 75
- The input number must avoid line `<+71>` inside `fun9` because that moves the number -1 inside
  of `$eax`, meaning that it can't ever make `$eax = 7`(I could be wrong?) as it will keep decrementing. This also implies that `$edx` shouldn't ever be 0 to pass through the test on line `<+12>` inside `fun9`

All I've tried doing is test different numbers and traced the registers inside `fun9` to see how `$eax` changes. I thought the answer was 75 as it was inside `$edx` but it's not. I know there are several recursion calls inside of this too - I'm trying to find an input where `$eax` is equal to 7 by the end of `fun9`.

Any tips on how I could try solving this? Are there any registers I'm missing? I'm looking at `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx` and `edx`.

Thank you.

Comment: You missed a data structure in memory. Hint: how many arguments does `fun9` take?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! @Jester I thought this was a BST.. how do I find out how many arguments fun9 takes in? I thought it only takes in one?

Comment: It is a BST, and `fun9` takes 2 arguments ..  the root and the number.

Comment: The number I inputted? That makes sense. But I'm just not sure how I should go about defusing the bomb? Because every time I trace the BST, I seem to be headed to a dead end and end up with a negative `eax` What tips would you suggest to finding the number? Thank you once again! @Jester

Comment: The tree contains values in nodes. You get a zero when your number is found. So, dump the tree and your input must be one of the values. You still need to figure out which one though :)

Comment: Makes sense haha, thanks. When you say I will get a zero when the number is found (The number needed to defuse the bomb, not my input I'm guessing?) you mean in one of the registers? @Jester Because from my understanding, the only way to break the recursion is when you get 0 when testing `edx`  ?

Comment: When `edx` is zero you get to the `return -1` that means the end of the tree was reached without finding your number. That's not what you want. You want the jump on line `+48` to be taken. The "number" refers to your input, yes.

Comment: Great, this helps a lot. Thanks so much! One final question; When you say 'dump the tree', how exactly can that be done without trying random numbers?  From what I've understood, 75 is the root of the tree, with 60 & 10 on the left (based on `ebx`) and 85 on the right. But none of these inputs are what I need to defuse the bomb so I'm a little stuck on how to go about traversing the tree? @Jester

Comment: That's just 3 nodes, you need to carry on. There will be more nodes deeper down. You can also approach from the other direction, knowing the return value must be `7` you can see which way the traversal must go so you can find the proper node.